# Where is the 8 byte explicit nonce for decrypting AES GCM within TLS?

Tags: tls, aes, ciphers, aead

I'm confused how to retrieve the remaining 8 bytes of the nonce (to combine with the 4 bytes established during the handshake) to generate the 12 byte IV to decrypt AES 128 GCM.

RFC 5288 "AES Galois Counter Mode (GCM) Cipher Suites for TLS" says this:

> The nonce_explicit is the "explicit" part of the nonce.  It is chosen
> by the sender and is carried in each TLS record in the
> GenericAEADCipher.nonce_explicit field.  The nonce_explicit length
> (SecurityParameters.record_iv_length) is 8 octets.

However, I cannot find a reference to describe what GenericAEADCipher struct looks like and where it is located within the received TLS record?

And does this IV creation vary between TLS 1.2 and 1.3?

Comment: 5288 only applies to TLS1.2, and AEAD in 1.2 is specified in the section named "AEAD Ciphers" (under "Record Payload Protection") in the RFC for 1.2 which is 5246 (and is referenced repeatedly from 5288). TLS1.3 does differ, using an "IV" from the key-schedule XORed with the (implicit) sequence number, and is specified in the RFC for 1.3 which is 8446 again under "Record Payload Protection".